# TFS 2015 SSL certificate could not be checked for revocation

Tags: ssl, tfs, winrm, certificate-revocation

I am using TFS 2015, I have a Release definition created for my test environment.  A task for "PowerShell on Target Machines" has been added.  The values are all entered correctly for this such as Machines, Admin Login, Password.  HTTPS is the protocol, The Test Certificate checkbox is checked.  WinRM listener is already setup on the remote server and working.  When I run this task it shows as Rejected.

The error is below:

### [error]Connecting to remote server myserver.example.com failed with the following error message : The server certificate on the destination computer (myserver.example.com:5986) has the following errors:

### [error]**The SSL certificate could not be checked for revocation. The server used to check for revocation might be unreachable**. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.

The TFS agent I am using does not have internet capability.  I tried this from another TFS agent that HAS internet capability and it worked.

Does anyone know if the TFS Agent must have internet capability?
Is there a way to skip the revocation checking from the User Interface?

Comment: Use a certificate without a CRL entry?

Comment: Did you try adding "-SkipRevocationCheck" argument in the task?

Answer (score 1):

Try to solution [here](http://cavaliercoder.com/blog/prevent-crl-check-for-powershell-remoting.html) to create and pass a new PSSessionOption object that specifies that all certificate checks should be bypassed.

```
$sessionOption = New-PSSessionOption -SkipCACheck -SkipCNCheck -SkipRevocationCheck
$session = New-PSSession -ConnectionUri $yourUrl -Credential $credential -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection -SessionOption $sessionOption
Import-PSSession $session
```